# Calculate percentage of results in week ranges starting from date

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, pivot-table, dynamic-sql

I have a table of data that shows attendance with the following columns.

PupilID, AttendanceDate, AttendanceSession, IsInAttendance(1 or 0)

**I need to be able to define a start and an end date (term dates) to run a query on that will show each pupils attendance percentage in each week.**

I am able to find each pupils total percentage % with the following code:

```
SELECT
    PupilID,
    ((SUM(CASE WHEN IsInAttendance = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100) / COUNT(IsInAttendance))  AS TotalAttPct
FROM #CombinedAttClSe
GROUP BY PupilID
```

I have the weeks of the year with the following code:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '2011-09-01 00:00:00.000';
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = '2011-12-31 00:00:00.000';

;WITH GetDates AS
(
    SELECT
        DATEADD(DAY, 0, @startdate) AS TheDate,
        DATEPART(WK, DATEADD(DAY, 1, @startdate)) WkNo,
        DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(DAY, 1, @startdate)) DateYear
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        DATEADD(DAY, 1, TheDate),
        DATEPART(WK, DATEADD(DAY, 1, TheDate)),
        DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(DAY, 1, TheDate))
        FROM GetDates
        WHERE TheDate < @enddate
)

SELECT
    WkNo,
    MIN(TheDate) AS SoW,
    MAX(TheDate) AS EoW
FROM GETDATES
GROUP BY WKNO
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

I'm not sure where to start to output this data as the following:

### PupilID | Week1 | Week2 | Week3 | Week 4| etc.

With each 'Week' heading containing a number to show the percentage of attendance.

EDIT:

From user suggestions I have tried to use PIVOT tables and dynamic SQL to solve this but am running into some issues. Below is the code I have so far.

```
CREATE TABLE #yt 
(
  [PupilID] int, 
  [WeekNo] int, 
  [IsInAttendance] int
);

INSERT INTO #yt
(
  [PupilID], 
  [WeekNo],
  [IsInAttendance]
)
VALUES
    (102, 1, 1),
    (102, 1, 1),
    (102, 1, 1),
    (102, 1, 1),
    (102, 1, 0),
    (102, 1, 1),
    (102, 1, 0),
    (102, 1, 1),
    (102, 2, 1),
    (102, 2, 1),
    (102, 2, 1),
    (102, 2, 1),
    (102, 2, 1),
    (102, 2, 1),
    (102, 2, 0),
    (102, 2, 1),
    (101, 1, 1),
    (101, 1, 1),
    (101, 1, 1),
    (101, 1, 1),
    (101, 1, 1),
    (101, 1, 1),
    (101, 1, 1),
    (101, 2, 1),
    (101, 2, 1),
    (101, 2, 1),
    (101, 2, 1),
    (101, 2, 0)

DECLARE @WkCols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @WkQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @WkCols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(WeekNo) 
                    FROM #yt
                    GROUP BY WeekNo
                    ORDER BY WeekNo
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @WkQuery = 'SELECT PupilID,' + @WkCols + ' FROM 
            (
                SELECT PupilID, WeekNo, IsInAttendance
                FROM #yt
            ) x
            PIVOT 
            (
                SUM(CASE WHEN IsInAttendance = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100 / COUNT(IsInAttendance) 
                FOR WeekNo IN (' + @WkCols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@WkQuery);
```

At the moment I am getting the error 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'.'

Any pointers or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Look into PIVOT tables if you haven't done so already - they are a bit complex sometimes, but useful for turning rows into columns.

Comment: You need to join the #CombinedAttClSe with the Weeks intervals using a `BETWEEN`, then pivot the result with dynamic SQL (since you don't know how many weeks your parameters will include).

Comment: @EzequielLopezPetrucci Hi Ezeuiel, I'm not sure I understand what you mean by 'join the #CombinedAttClSe with the Weeks interval'.

Sorry if i'm missing something easy but would you be able to explain further?

Comment: I'm guessing that table #CombinedAttClSe holds the attendances for each pupil for a particular date. If so, you need to join that table with the last query from your 2nd query (the one with WkNo and Min/Max dates) so you can know the pupil's attendance % for each week.

Comment: @EzequielLópezPetrucci Thank you for pointing me in the correct direction.

After some googling I have [found this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/580183)

Which I will try to amend to fit my needs now.

Comment: Yes, that will work. Just make sure that column "xCount" (in the link you mentioned) already holds the attendances % before pivoting.

Comment: @EzequielLópezPetrucci Hi Ezequiel, I have added some more information in an edit to the question.

I'm a little bit confused as to how I would calculate the attendance % before doing the pivot, because I need to calculate the weekly attendance % but I can't group it by week and pupil before the pivot?

Any guidance at would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't apply complex aggregates on a `PIVOT` aggregate function unfortunately. So you will have to make do with a simple `SUM` or `MAX`. Try calculating the attendance percentage before pivoting:

```
SELECT
    T.PupilID,
    T.WeekNo,
    AttendancePercentage = SUM(T.IsInAttendance) * 100.0 / COUNT(1)
FROM
    #yt AS T
GROUP BY
    T.PupilID,
    T.WeekNo
```

And the pivot:

```
DECLARE @WkCols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @WkQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @WkCols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(WeekNo) 
                    FROM #yt
                    GROUP BY WeekNo
                    ORDER BY WeekNo
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @WkQuery = 'SELECT PupilID,' + @WkCols + ' FROM 
            (
                SELECT
                    T.PupilID,
                    T.WeekNo,
                    AttendancePercentage = SUM(T.IsInAttendance) * 100.0 / COUNT(1)
                FROM
                    #yt AS T
                GROUP BY
                    T.PupilID,
                    T.WeekNo
            ) x
            PIVOT 
            (
                MAX(AttendancePercentage) 
                FOR WeekNo IN (' + @WkCols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@WkQuery);
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Definitely answered my question as well as providing great guidance along the way to help me understand.

Comment: Glad to help :)